# Ubuntu 16.04.2 freezes after startup

Tags: 16.04, freeze, io

I left Ubuntu a while ago after Ubuntu 16.04 came out and was totally unstable, and tried another distro, and couple days ago after I saw that Ubuntu 16.04.2 was released I thought that probably some major improvements were made, but clearly its still unstable.
So after I installed it and installed the software I need for my daily life, I got a problem which was that the screen was turning black and flickering from time to town, turns out the wrong Graphics card driver was installed, so I handled that, and after couple hours I got another problem, when I boot Ubuntu and the desktop shows up (I have it log me in automatically) the screen freezes, and I can't move the mouse around, can't launch anything using a shortcut, can't load a hard shell using Alt+Ctrl+F1, but from the other hand I have a removable wireless adapter which has its led on, so when I remove it the wireless connections tray changed to indicate that I've disconnected, and plugging it back Ubuntu automatically connects to my home Wifi.
I haven't upgraded the system using apt-get upgrade after installation, I have it on dual boot with Windows 10 Creators Update, and my system specs are: Lenovo B560, 6GB RAM, Intel Graphics, Intel I3 370M, Toshiba 320GB HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing a package Ubuntu:
`apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`

Answer (score 0):

What graphical drivers are you using?

I suspect the issue will most likely either be an issue with Xorg or GPU drivers, always is with Ubuntu.

Comment: I did apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel

Comment: Check the additional drivers tab in system settings -> software and updates for any more drivers you can use